# folder permissions on FreeBSD

Tags: unix, permissions, freebsd, chmod, freenas

I have a drive on my FreeNas (8.2) box which transmission copies files automatically when it is finished downloading them.  It works fine as long as the download is a single file, if it's folder with files in it I have a problem to move them because of permissions.

I set the root folder downloads as chmod -R 777 but the new folders are always 644 I think.  I'm not hugely knowledgeable with UNIX/BSD file permissions.  Is there a way to set the permissions over the folder for folders that future downloaded folder (which do not yet exist) receive the same rights as the parent? or is it only something that can be solved with the settings of transmission which sets the permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask). It looks like Transmission has umask in it's configuration ([doc](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles)). Your shell will generally maintain this. If you are talking about network shares the daemon might control the defaults on newly created files ([Samba's doc](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html#samba2-CHP-8-SECT-2.1)).